# Using AnyAsync() on an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, asynchronous, query-optimization

I am writing a `PostList` method for my API. Before posting, I have a check to see if any of the items already exist in the database:

```
if (myArray.Any(item => dbSet.Any(it => it.id == item.id)))
{
  return UnprocessableEntity("Object already exists in the database.");
}
```

But I am uncertain whether each item would need to return from the database for the next item to be considered, or whether LINQ magic would send the whole query at once (or if LINQ even applies to array queries), as well as whether or not this would block other connections from getting their data. So I tried changing this to `AnyAsync`:

```
if (await myArray.AsQueryable().AnyAsync(item => dbSet.Any(it => it.id == item.id)))
{
  return UnprocessableEntity("Object already exists in the database.");
}
```

but I get the error `The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider.` (I also tried adding `AnyAsync` to the inner query.... let's just say things got really confusing very fast)

What can I do to make sure the query is optimized for parallel execution, or is it already doing things as efficiently as it can as is?

FWIW: A previous pattern in related code uses `await dbSet.Where(e => e.id == myItem.id).FirstOrDefaultAsync() != null` to check if a single item already exists, and some other places wrapped similar statements in a `foreach` block. Am I just suffering from optimizitis, or is what I'm trying to do actually a better way to perform this check?

Comment: The big issue with `myArray.Any(item => dbSet.Any(it => it.id == item.id))` is that you're going to run one query against the DB for each item in `myArray` until the inner `Any` returns true.  I'd suggest changing to `dbSet.Any(it => myArray.Contains(it.id))` instead so it's just one query and you should be able to use `AnyAsync` as well.  This assumes `myArray` is an array of a primitive DB type like `int` or `string` or even `Guid`.

Comment: `myArray` is composed of objects containing primitives. And there's no guarantee that the primary key will be the field compared for uniqueness (actually it's guaranteed that it won't be, because this check happens just before assigning values to the primary key, which now that I think of it, I might want to figure out how to ensure that these values don't get sniped). So I don't know if `Contains` will be my best bet here.

Comment: @juharr Wouldn't it also be doing more checks this way?

Comment: No, because it would be turned into one SQL query.  What you can do is create an array of the ids you want to compare to like `var myIds = myArray.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray()` then use that like `dbSet.Any(it => myIds.Contains(it.id))`;

Comment: @juharr It's starting to look like it just won't work at all - linq has failed to translate all the variations I've tried so far. Still a few more to try.